# Unable to run hellojni

Tags: android, android-ndk

I can not start hellojni project via AndroidStudio. I have got this error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
D:\Programs\android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=D:\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
2Output:
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `D:\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hello-jni/D_\hello-jni\app\src\main\jni', needed by `D:\hello-jni\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hello-jni/D_\hello-jni\app\src\main\jni\hello-jni.o'.  Stop.
```

Links what I have found don't help me. NDK_PROJECT_PATH leads to root of ndk but issue wtill exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is related to this bug I've reported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937

There is a simple workaround: creating a second .c file (it can be empty) next to hello-jni.c.

Comment: Workaround helps. Thank you!